# R: Import CSV with double quotes only on text

Tags: r, import, double-quotes

I am trying to import a CSV where the text columns are in double quotes but the numeric columns are not. I have 95 columns in total so I cannot manually modify the columns. (Note: There are commas in the text that I cannot remove)

Below is a sample data set to illustrate my problem.

CSV File:

```
"Column 1","Column 2","Column 3","Column 4","Column 5"

2,"A,A","B,Z","C,C",44

3,"A,X","B,B","C,C",121
```

Desired Output:

```
Column 1    Column 2  Column3   Column4 Column5
   2          A,A      B,Z        C,C       44
   3          A,X      B,B        C,C      121
```

I tried:

```
       test=read.csv('test.csv', header=TRUE,sep =",")
```

Comment: I was able to get the desired output by copy/pasting your input and reading it using the code you showed.  (I used `R 3.2.0`)

Comment: works for me with code you tried, but on text that had blank lines removed. If these exist and cause problem, use readlines and remove "\n" lines or all even lines.

Comment: Sorry, The title row had double quotes also. I modified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tf <- tempfile()
csv <- '"Column 1","Column 2","Column 3","Column 4","Column 5"\n\n2,"A,A","B,Z","C,C",44\n\n3,"A,X","B,B","C,C",121'
writeLines( csv , tf )
x <- read.csv( tf )

      Column.1 Column.2 Column.3 Column.4 Column.5
1        2      A,A      B,Z      C,C       44
2        3      A,X      B,B      C,C      121
```

Comment: Your code does not work when I import directly from the CSV file. How can I replicate line 2 of your code without writing the data directly?

Comment: @SamerNachabé  you need to post a reproducible example probably with `readLines( your_csv_file , n = 3 )`

Answer (score 0):

Remove blank lines as `read.table` can't accept them

```
readLines(textConnection(txt)) -> rl  # readLines('csvfile.csv') for you
rl[1:length(rl) %% 2 == 1] -> rl2
read.table(text = rl2, sep = ',', h = TRUE)
```

**Output:**

```
  Column.1 Column.2 Column.3 Column.4 Column.5
1        2      A,A      B,Z      C,C       44
2        3      A,X      B,B      C,C      121
```

**Data:**

```
txt <- '"Column 1","Column 2","Column 3","Column 4","Column 5"

2,"A,A","B,Z","C,C",44

3,"A,X","B,B","C,C",121'
```

Comment: You don't have to remove blank lines as the default option is `blank.lines.skip = TRUE` and it worked for me without doing any alterations with the OP's data

Comment: You're right. Need to see what happened that it didn't work at first attempt. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Ok, so `read.table` doesn't work, while `read.csv' works fine as in Anthony's answer

Comment: I tried with `read.table` and it worked.  May be some difference in R version.  I used R 3.2.0

Comment: `> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)   
Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: openSUSE 13.1 (Bottle) (x86_64)`  Strange

Comment: mine is `sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS`